# Comparing two directories with same name text files and unmatch regex findall

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, csv, file

I have two directories in which I have text files with same matching file names. I need to compare same name texts files respectively and write out the unmatched words in csv with respective file name.

```
Folder1:
  file1.txt   file2.txt

Folder2: 
  file1.txt   file2.txt
```

Here i need findall unmatched words from comparing the two. I have something like below

```
stat="files, unmatch_words\n"
pack=os.list('./Folder1/')
for file in pack:
    package=open('./Folder1/' + file, 'r').read()
    grep=open("./Folder2/" + file,'r').read()
    output= re.findall(r'(\w+)',grep)
    rex=(set(output))
    stat += file.replace('.txt', '') + ',"'

    for sem in rex:
        if sem not in package:
            stat += sem + '\n'
stat += '","'
stat += '"' + '\n'
f=open('file.csv', 'w')
f.write(stat)
```

This combines all files in **Folder2** (i.e **rex**) in to one and comparing it with files in **Folder1**.

I want to unmatch words from **Folder1** -> **file1.txt** with **Folder2** -> **file1.txt** like wise **Folder1** -> **file2.txt** with **Folder2** -> **file2.txt**

Can anyone please suggest any update on this. Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use python? It might be worth using `diff` in bash.

Comment: Yes, as i'm writing it in csv file.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html might be helpful

Comment: The best way to go about this is what @theEpsilon has put across. use the `diff` function. I am kind of convinced that almost all OS come with this function. open the terminal and try running `diff --help` is the function present?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of functionality is trivial with [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)

Example:

Given these two files:

```
% cat file1.txt
line 1
line 2
blah bligh blah line 3
line 4
line 5
% cat file2.txt
line 1
blip blop bloop line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

The unix diff utility shows this difference:

```
% diff file1.txt file2.txt
2,3c2,3
< line 2
< blah bligh blah line 3
---
> blip blop bloop line 2
> line 3
```

You can trivially replicate diff with Python's difflib:

```
from difflib import Differ 
d=Differ()

with open(f1_name) as f1, open(f2_name) as f2:  
    print(''.join(d.compare(f1.readlines(),f2.readlines())))
```

Prints:

```
  line 1
+ blip blop bloop line 2
- line 2
?      ^
+ line 3
?      ^
- blah bligh blah line 3
  line 4
  line 5
```

To replicate this with a regex alone is not really possible.

The four character `' ', '+', '?', '-'` allow you to programmatically separate which file has which change (left or right) you could then write those changes to a csv file.

If you poke around in difflib you will likely get the direction you need on this.

If you are only looking for word by word differences, you can use a set:

```
with open(f1_name) as f1, open(f2_name) as f2:      
    s1={word for line in f1 for word in line.split()}
    s2={word for line in f2 for word in line.split()}

>>> s1-s2
{'blah', 'bligh'}            # words only in file1
>>> s2-s1
{'blip', 'blop', 'bloop'}    # words only in file2
```

Comment: Still Not possible as the file is so big i need to use regex to short it and compare later. i saw your comment using regex its not possible. Is there any other method so that i can short the text then compare.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use regex personally.
You can split the words by whitespaces, put them into two lists and check the unmatched:

```
    #get words in those files, splited by whitespaces
    packageWords=package.split()
    grepWords=grep.split()
    #words in package but not in grep
    unmatchedWordsPackage=[word for word in packageWords if not word in grepWords]
    #words in grep but not in package
    unmatchedWordsGrep=[word for word in grepWords if not word in packageWords]
    #merge the two lists into one big string
    unmatchedWords=' '.join(unmatchedWordsGrep) + ' ' + ' '.join(unmatchedWordsGrep)
```

Comment: i need to use regex as its too big content with more punctuation. Your solution is not appropriate for me and thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, csv
path1 = "stackoverflow/Folder1"
path2 = "stackoverflow/Folder2"
files = os.listdir(path1)
for file in files: 
    folder1_data = open("%s/%s" % (path1, file), 'r').read() 
    folder2_data = open("%s/%s" % (path2, file), 'r').read() 
    folder1_data = folder1_data.replace("\n", " ") 
    folder2_data = folder2_data.replace("\n", " ") 
    folder1_data = folder1_data.strip() 
    folder1_data = folder1_data.split(" ") 
    folder2_data = folder2_data.strip() 
    folder2_data = folder2_data.split(" ") 
    output = list(set(folder1_data).union(set(folder2_data)) - set(folder1_data).intersection(set(folder2_data))) 
    with open("stackoverflow/" + file.replace("txt", "csv"), 'w') as csv_file: 
        file_writer = csv.writer(csv_file) 
        file_writer.writerow(output)
```